# macOS: Identify tool and keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, shortcut

While working on a project in Xcode, when attempting to take a screenshot, I mistakenly invoked a random keyboard shortcut for some graphic/UI tool, instead of <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> which I actually wanted to invoke.

It showed the following screen with three tabs (Screenshot, Screen recording and a 3rd item that I can't recall) on top. It also shows a smaller view where a square was shown split into four with some coordinates and colour code at the bottom:

[image]

I have tried, but I couldn't reproduce the keyboard shortcut again. What is the tool and what is the exact shortcut? I am using a Late 2013 15" MacBook Pro with US International keyboard, running macOS Mojave 10.14.2.

**Note**: Kindly notice the two controls highlighted in the screenshot. The top is a tab like interface with three buttons (third one is selected with white background). If you'll notice carefully, the button background is a shade of dark grey which closely matches with Xcode dark interface. Just below that is some kind of UI tool with a box with 4 squares, coordinates and RGB colour codes.

Answer (score 1):

It's the new feature in Mojave. You can show Screenshot/Screen Capture menu with <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried this keyboard shortcut before asking the question and I am aware of the screenshot tool introduced in macOS Mojave. This is clearly a different tool. Kindly see the updated in the question.

Comment: Ah now I see that it's something different.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>  captures a selected portion of the screen.

It seems like you got confused with the keys you pressed and that is why you couldn't replicate it.

From [this Support article:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361#earlier)

> **Capture a window**
>
> Press Shift-Command-4.
>
> Press the Space bar. The pointer changes to a camera . Click a window
>   to capture that window.
>
> To exclude the window's shadow from the screenshot, press and hold the
>   Option  (⌥) key while you click.
>
> Find the screenshot as a .png file on your desktop.

Comment: Did you read the question clearly?